# Derivative of a distribution is a distribution

Tags: partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

Let T be a distribution and define its derivative as

$$D^\alpha T:=\phi\ \rightarrow (-1)^{|\alpha|}T(D^\alpha \phi)$$

Show that the distributional derivative is a distribution as well.

So, I need to show that the map is linear and continuous. For linearity:

$$D^\alpha T(a_1x_1+a_2x_2)=(-1)^{|\alpha|}T(D^\alpha(a_1x_1+a_2x_2))$$ and since the differential operator $D^\alpha$ is linear and T is a distribution and hence linear, this is equal to $a_1(-1)^{|\alpha|}T(D^\alpha x_1)+a_2(-1)^{|\alpha|}T(D^\alpha x_2)$ which means that $D^aT$ is linear.

Is this proof correct? I struggle to show that the map is continuous. Any hints on this?

Answer (score 1):

Take $\phi_k \in \mathcal{D}.$ Since $\phi_k \to \phi$ in $\mathcal{D}$ implies that $\partial^\alpha\phi_k \to \partial^\alpha\phi$ in $\mathcal{D}$ (show this claim!) it's easy:
$$
\langle \partial^\alpha T, \phi_k \rangle
= (-1)^{|\alpha|} \langle T, \partial^\alpha \phi_k \rangle
\to (-1)^{|\alpha|} \langle T, \partial^\alpha \phi \rangle
= \langle \partial^\alpha T, \phi \rangle.
$$

Comment: Could you explain how to show that $D^\alpha \phi_k \rightarrow D^\alpha \phi$? To show convergence in D, I'd need to show that all supports of $\phi_k$ are in one compact set and all derivatives converge uniformly in U.

Comment: @illuminatitruthseeker. I didn't mention here that I assume that $\phi_k \to \phi$ in $\mathcal D.$ If all supports of $\phi_k$ are in one compact set $K,$ can the support of $\partial^\alpha\phi_k$ go outside of $K$? If $\partial^\alpha \phi_k \to \partial^\alpha \phi$ uniformly **for all $\alpha,$** what can be said about $\partial^{\alpha+\beta} \phi_k$?

Comment: Intuitively, I'd say that the derivative can't go outisde $K$ but I don't know how to explain why. Also what can I say about $\partial^{\alpha+\beta} \phi_k$?

Comment: @illuminatitruthseeker. What's the value of $\phi_k$ outside of $K$? If you change the point $x$ slightly, so that you are still outside of $K,$ how much does $\phi_k(x)$ change?

Comment: @illuminatitruthseeker. Is $\partial^{\alpha+\beta} \phi_k$ in the set $\{ \partial^\alpha \phi_k \mid \alpha\text{ a multi-index} \}$?